# AUCTeX: ` a inserts \alpha{}: How can one omit the curly braces to be inserted?

Tags: emacs, auctex

According to an AUCTeX reference card, <kbd>` a</kbd> inserts `\alpha{}` and this works well in my setup. I just don't see any reason I ever used a greek letter with curly braces. This means I always have to delete them. Is there a way to have AUCTeX insert just `\alpha` when typing <kbd>` a</kbd>?

Comment: If you do it inside math mode, e.g. inside `\( \)` or `$ $`, it will omit the curly braces.

Comment: Great! I should have experimented a bit more first :-)

Comment: You should have but this is a problem I am sure others have stumbled upon too so I think the question make sense. Since it helped you I converted my comment into [an answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51218/auctex-a-inserts-alpha-how-can-one-omit-the-curly-braces-to-be-inserted/51247#51247).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may not be any reason to disable this behavior since the braces *are* omitted if used inside math mode. When you do <kbd>` a</kbd> inside any structure that enables math mode, such as inside `\( \)`, `$ $`, `equation` or `align`, AUCTeX will omit the braces. For example the behavior for `equation` is the following:

1. `(cursor)` is not really in the code but just to mark where the cursor is.

   ```
   \begin{equation}
     (cursor)
   \end{equation}
   ```
2. You press <kbd>` a</kbd>.

   ```
   \begin{equation}
     \alpha
   \end{equation}
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can also put the line

```lisp
(setq TeX-insert-braces nil)
```

into your init file to keep the braces from ever being inserted when AUCTeX inserts a macro.